# Schedule auto wallpaper changing in background

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jobscheduler, android-wallpaper

how can we set a background task to android so that at given time an image is loaded from URL and set as wallpaper

Comment: what exactly is a problem of all those? 1) How to set a background image in Android? 2) How to download file from URL? 3) How to execute code after time?

Comment: Could you include some code or examples of what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code to set the wallpaper

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

AND u need to addd this permission in your manfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

and you need JobDispatcher to runa task periodically.

```
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)

            .setTag("DAILY-MAIN-SYNC")
            .setRecurring(true)   //  setRecurring
            // don't persist past a device reboot
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(1, (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)))
            .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
            .build();
    dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
```

this job will run each day

now create `MyJobService extends JobService`

in in the

```
@Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) { ....
```

write the code I wrote above.

Hope this will guide you to the right track.

Comment: thank you, Tried it and works some times.But how can we set it to a fixed time everyday or like a 2 hr interval

Comment: using this line 
  .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(1, (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)))

Comment: can you please  give +1 to the answer and accept it

Comment: No it should not I use it when there some background tasks that should work even if the user is not using the app

Comment: But for me it works until the app stays in the recents, but onece terminated the job is not done.It will initiate agin and works suddenly if the app is agin launched after the given time.Currently using Android 8.0,is there anything extra to add.

Comment: Thankyou its working now after turning of androids background optimization on Oxygen OS.

Comment: Sry buddy i would really like to but my rank is below 15.